# how to switch characters in a data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
ID        S01       S02       S03       S04       S05
M01       0|1       0|0       1|1       1|1       1|1
M02       0|0       0|0       0|0       1|1       1|0
M03       0|0       0|0       0|0       1|1       0|0
M04       0|1       0|1       0|1       0|0       0|1
M05       0|0       0|0       0|0       1|1       0|0
```

I would like to switch "0" and "1" each other. The result is expected:

```
ID        S01       S02       S03       S04       S05
M01       1|0       1|1       0|0       0|0       0|0
M02       1|1       1|1       1|1       0|0       0|1
M03       1|1       1|1       1|1       0|0       1|1
M04       1|0       1|0       1|0       1|1       1|0
M05       1|1       1|1       1|1       0|0       1|1
```

It can be done by replace "0" to an intermediate value such as "2" or whatever, then replace "1" to "0", and replace the intermediate value back to "1". is there any efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `chartr` to replace 1 with 0 and viceversa.  Loop through the columns (`lapply(df1[-1]`, ) and change the characters with `chartr`

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], chartr, old = '01', new = '10')
df1
#   ID S01 S02 S03 S04 S05
#1 M01 1|0 1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
#2 M02 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|1
#3 M03 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1
#4 M04 1|0 1|0 1|0 1|1 1|0
#5 M05 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("M01", "M02", "M03", "M04", "M05"),
S01 = c("0|1", 
"0|0", "0|0", "0|1", "0|0"), S02 = c("0|0", "0|0", "0|0", "0|1", 
"0|0"), S03 = c("1|1", "0|0", "0|0", "0|1", "0|0"), S04 = c("1|1", 
"1|1", "1|1", "0|0", "1|1"), S05 = c("1|1", "1|0", "0|0", "0|1", 
"0|0")), .Names = c("ID", "S01", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S05"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch = function(x){
    if(x == "0|0") return("1|1")
    if(x == "1|0") return("0|1")
    if(x == "0|1") return("1|0")
    if(x == "1|1") return("0|0")
    return(NA)
}
```

`apply()` (MARGIN = c(1, 2), of course) this to your data frame and it should be plenty efficient and easy to read and understand to everyone reading your code.

*EDIT to address comment:*
Given the dataframe df1 from akrun`s (very elegant) answer you can simply do

```
apply(df1[,-1], 1:2, switch)
```

or, to preserve the ID column:

```
cbind(ID=df1[,1], apply(df1[,-1], 1:2, switch))
```

My approach obviously only works, because there are few combinations. If there were more zeros and ones, the chartr approach is much more feasible. With only four possible combinations, this is more readable.

Comment: You should call your function something besides `switch` because that's already a function, though it's not often used because it's not vectorized. You actually could here, though: `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x){Vectorize(function(y){switch(as.character(y), '0|0' = '1|1', '0|1' = '1|0', '1|0' = '0|1', '1|1' = '0|0')})(x)})`. dplyr has a vectorized version called `case_when` which works well if implemented in purrr: `library(tidyverse) ; df %>% dmap_at(2:6, ~case_when(.x == '0|0' ~ '1|1', .x == '0|1' ~ '1|0', .x == '1|0' ~ '0|1', .x == '1|1' ~ '0|0'))`. It's the same idea regardless.

Comment: @alistaire I like your first version better than mine. Your `switch` is readable and less repetitive. So far it's my favorite in this thread.

Comment: Wait, you can actually simplify it: `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], Vectorize(function(x){switch(as.character(x), '0|0' = '1|1', '0|1' = '1|0', '1|0' = '0|1', '1|1' = '0|0')}))`. It's really just an overcomplicated lookup table, though, so you might as well just do `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x){c('0|0' = '1|1', '0|1' = '1|0', '1|0' = '0|1', '1|1' = '0|0')[x]})`